# How to change extra spaces into tabs

Tags: awk

I have file with lot of extra spaces or double tabs etc. is it possible to change all of them into tab separated ?

I tried this

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $0}'
```

input

```
E       0.000000 0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000    0.000000 0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000    0.000000 0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000    0.000000 0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0       0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000        0.000000
```

Comment: Can you add to the question one row of your data for which you get an unexpected result?

Comment: sorry. i figure out the problem. The script was fine but there were extra spaces. I changed the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/\s+/\t/g' file
```

If your sed doesn't support `\s` use `[[:space:]]`.

Or:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

The awk script will also strip off leading and trailing white space.

Comment: +1, concise & precise, as always. I'd add a note to explain that the awk version does 2 things: 1st action is a `{$1=$1}` (with no preceding condition, so it does so on every lines), which forces awk to re-evaluate $0 (which have (desired) side-effect to replace, between each $n, N whitespaces with just 1). 2nd action is just a condition `1` which is always "true" (you could use "2", "toto" or a lot of other things as well), and which will print $0 (as a true condition not followed by `{some statements}` will do the default action instead : print $0), using the newly defined OFS, "tab"

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
sed 's/ \+/\t/g' file
```

example

```
kent$  echo "a       b    c             d"|sed 's/ \+/\t/g' 
a       b       c       d
```